# Overriding default view and template for a model in django / passing variables to grapelli template

Tags: python, django, templates, view, django-grappelli

I am using django admin and grappelli and wanted to override the default view for a certain model.

I overrode the grapelli `change_form` template:

```

```
{% extends "grappelli:admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script type="text/javascript">{{Object}}</script>
 {% endblock %}
```

```

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I access the model that is passed by default by django? Neither `Object` nor `opts` seem to work.
2. How do I override the default to view (what's the method I need to override) to add new variables into template context?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override with change_view in admin.py and pass variables through extra_context. e.g:

```
class GivenModel(models.Model):
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):

                your_obj = GivenModel.objects.get(id=asset_id.group(1))
                extra_context = {'title': your_obj.description}
            return super(GivenModel, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```